# React.js with XUL for Firefox development

Tags: reactjs, xul

React.js was designed to work with HTML. How about XUL, sort of HTML? When I tried to run them together I got an error:
`Target container is not a DOM element.`

Basically I don't see the reason why React.js shouldn't work with XUL. I would like to hear some opinions or suggestions for this subject.

Comment: React was designed for a DOM. Not "sort of a DOM." It needs to have all the features that it needs from the browser. a XUL element isn't an HTMLElement.

Comment: The Document Object Model (DOM) is a technical standard promulgated by the W3C, and is an API for manipulating the contents of XML documents as objects. 
Since XUL is a type of XML, I don't see a clear reasoning in the previous answer.

Comment: I just found out that: XUL lacks any equivalent for the innerHTML property. So this might be a reason...

Answer (score 1):

React.js tests for the DOM as follows:

```
var canUseDOM = !!(
 typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
 window.document &&
 window.document.createElement
);
```

whereas XUL works as follows:

> You can get a Window object from a document using document.defaultView.
>
> Assume you have a document loaded in a `<tabbrowser>`, `<browser>`, or `<iframe>` element inside your document. You can use browser.contentDocument to access that document and browser.contentWindow to access the Window object of that document.

**References**

- [ReactMount.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/dom/client/ReactMount.js#L405)
- [ReactDOM.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/isomorphic/classic/element/ReactDOM.js)
- [geMarkupWrap.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/shared/vendor/core/getMarkupWrap.js)
- [ReactDOMComponent.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/dom/shared/ReactDOMComponent.js)
- [ExecutionEnvironment.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/shared/vendor/core/ExecutionEnvironment.js)
- [MDN: Inner and Outer Windows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Inner_and_outer_windows)
- [MDN: Working with Windows in Chrome code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code)